# how to import from MS excel into MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, excel

How do I import data from MS excel and insert in to MYSQL database  ?
Which language is easiest and fastest to do this task ?

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 6):

If you can safely represent everything in a CSV format (just export from Excel) then you need only one command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/coolfile.txt' INTO TABLE coolTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the swiss army knife of data manipulation in the windows world:

MS Access

Import the Excel sheet into an Access table, and export the table over ODBC to MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Not really a programming question, the fastest method I would suggest is export data from Excel to CSV-file, and then import it into MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can use phpMyAdmin's `import` feature. It has many options including import from Microsoft Excel!