# To import data from excel to mysql database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to import from MS excel into MYSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432347/how-to-import-from-ms-excel-into-mysql-db)

I wish to import some data from excel to mysql database. my query is

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:/Book1.csv' INTO TABLE exp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

I receive an error File 'd:/Book1.csv' not found. Is there anything i want to do.

Comment: This utility is the easiest way to go... http://panofish.net/convert-import-excel-spreadsheets-into-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tool for this called [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).

That's what I use to import data to my database, I'm not sure if it supports a mysql database, but I think it does.

Well, this is a good way to do it if you don't want to do it at runtime with code.

Tjekkles