# Step By Step procedure to migrate data from Excel to MySql database table

Tags: mysql, excel, data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to import from MS excel into MYSQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432347/how-to-import-from-ms-excel-into-mysql-db)

I want the procedure to migrate the excel data into mysql database.
Supppose i have excel abc.xls and table in MySql is abc
Now what will be step by step procedure .
I am using MYSQL.

Please help

Comment: It's been asked many times on SO. There's one solution by exporting to CSV and using the SQL command [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). You could also open the table in PHPMyAdmin and import the Excel file. Just search a bit.

Comment: I posted a good list of options to accomplish this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database/25578291#25578291

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to use a MySQL client like [SQLyog](http://webyog.com/en/downloads.php). It has a wizard which allows for easy migration from excel to MySQL.

You can also use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command to import it directly. 
Take a look at [this](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html) for the detailed steps

Answer (score 0):

Try [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) (Excel format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Command line is supported.